# Running googletest in docker

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, googletest

**Summary:**
I am trying to run google test inside a docker. When running in the docker, the address of the cmake cache file changes. When I try to run the tests, a cmake error occurs saying The Current CMakeCache.txt directory is different than the directory it was created.

**Detail:**
I have previously run the tests separately (different project without docker) and they worked. I am using the same file to run the tests inside the docker, but it keeps giving the error. GTest has been built inside the docker. The cmake file and the test files are attached in the code blocks below:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include(GoogleTest)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_SOURCES "cpp/test.cc" )

add_executable(test_main ${TEST_SOURCES})
set_target_properties(test_main
    PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
)
set(PThreadLib -pthread)
target_include_directories(test_main
    PRIVATE
        ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}

        )
target_link_libraries(test_main
    -pthread
    
    ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
)

gtest_discover_tests(test_main)
```

test.cc:

```
TEST(ExampleTests, Macros)
{
    EXPECT_FALSE(true);
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

TEST(ExampleTests, Macros2)
{
    EXPECT_FALSE(false);
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

TEST(ExampleTests, Macros3)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(true, 1);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

**My testing method:** I am running this on a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB. I am using SSH using Visual Studio Code, and invoke the test using CMake: Run Tests from the command palette. I've rebuilt the files, removed and then rebuilt the cache, tried testing with and without running the docker. The end result is always the same. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are mixing 3 thins which should not impact each other: `cmake` as  build process, writing test, running test (in docker). If they do then you didn't provide information needed to see this interaction. And there is Raspberry which makes your question even more confusing. Maybe you have problem with cross compiling?